# Grabbing data from a bloomberg terminal on python

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi, rblpapi, pdblp

I am familiar with using xbbg and blp in python to grab bloomberg data for certain securities.

I am now trying to grab a list of all active SPACS under SPAC monitor (SPAX). Does anyone know what function would be most appropriate to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programming to grab data from Bloomberg terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226806/programming-to-grab-data-from-bloomberg-terminal)

Comment: I don't think you can get that data through the API.

Comment: My usual approach is to see if I can get the data in Excel and then look to port to Python. If you can’t get it in Excel then you won’t get it via Python, but the reverse is not true. SPACs are a relatively new product: you may want to ask your Bloomi rep if the list can be accessed via BQL in Excel.