# Is there any way to determine/count how many requests you made to bloomberg from excel?

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

If you do refresh Bloomerg formulas in excel, Is there any way to determine/count how many requests you made to Bloomberg from excel?

Right now I am using lots of `BDP/BDH` formulas to get data from Bloomberg with help of `Bloomberg excel add-in/API`.
to get bechmark prices like `arrival price,close price,prev_close,VWAP,VSOT` etc..

Bloomberg terminal has data downloading limit. Bloomberg associates its data limits with paid licenses. 
I download data using bloomberg excel formulas.whenever I refresh worksheet, the formulas download the data again.
So I need to check how many request are going from my excel tool to bloomberg for data downloading.

Is there any way **to count how many time a formula get calculated in excel?**

Comment: I think only people who have worked with Bloomberg file before can answer this. If you need more people to have a look at this, I would suggest that you either provide a sample of the file or point us to where we can get to this file so that we can have a .. play :)

Comment: You could try using wireshark to count the requests

Comment: This is not too broad. The question is about a specific problem OP is trying to solve: How can you keep track of how many times you hit Bloomberg for data? Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791271, but none of the answers there really answer the question.